# Memcpy copies more, than expected

Tags: c, memcpy

I'm trying to copy x bytes. The size is counted and printed out(see below). I use memcpy to copy the counted amount of bytes. But as result I'm getting sometimes longer values. What is wrong?

This is a few of the code:

```
  size_t  symlen  = tmpP - cp;
  char * triP = malloc(symlen);
  printf("mallocated %zu\n", symlen) ;
  memcpy (triP, tmpP - (symlen) , symlen);
  printf(">>VAL %s<<\n", triP);
```

Here is some output and you can see, that value is longer as 15 characters.

```
mallocated 15
>>VAL 558657,1033,8144399,814<<
mallocated 15
>>VAL 558657,1033,8144399,814<<
```

Comment: Does `symlen` account for the trailing `\0` character required by `printf`? Is there a trailing `\0`?

Comment: Printing as `%s` assumes this is a zero-terminated string. If this is all you wrote, you forgot to (manually!) add the terminating zero.

Comment: What is the type of tmpP, cp ??? memcpy takes dst and src pointers and no of bytes to be copied, What is th second parameter you are sending to memcpy? It may be the case that you are reading junk data

Comment: I haven't showed  tmpP nor cp , because it IMHO was not necessary for finding the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should allocate one more byte, and write a null character in it to mark the end of the string.

```
size_t  symlen  = tmpP - cp;
char * triP = malloc(symlen+1);
printf("mallocated %zu\n", symlen) ;
memcpy (triP, tmpP - (symlen) , symlen);
tripP[symlen] = '\0';
printf(">>VAL %s<<\n", triP);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you haven't added the null byte to the memcpy'd data. It looks like memcpy must've marked the page where it copied the string as copy-on-write, so when one accesses `triP`, one is actually accessing `tmpP` and thus the value of `triP` shown in the second `printf` is `tmpP` instead of gibberish data.